# Open the barcode scanner via website in genexus

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I know that the Genexus Scanner object only works on smart device panels, but I was wondering if there is a way to open a barcode reader with a button in a normal web panel and have the result returned.

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner in GeneXus is only available for Android and iOS native applications.

You could try adding a third-party library, wrapped in a [User Control object](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?39356,Category%3AUser%20Control%20object), and then add it to your Web Panels... I've just found [this one](https://blog.minhazav.dev/QR-and-barcode-scanner-using-html-and-javascript/), that worked in my iPhone's Safari browser, but there may be others.